# Spring Data: Getting NonUniqueResult Problem for the query

Tags: postgresql, spring-boot, spring-data

Hello experts of the world. Need some help concerning executing a query with SpringData.

The expectation is to execute the Query below in the Spring Data annotation by combining with the repository method name (Automated Query Construction) to get a unique result. Apparently it fails from time to time by saying the result is not Unique.
The question here is if the method name is still considered in Query Construction while also executing the query in the annotation.

```
 @Query("SELECT r from Revision r WHERE r.revisionBid = ?1 AND r.revisionStatusId = ?2 ORDER BY r.lastModifiedDate DESC")
 Optional<Revision> findFirst(Integer revisionBid, Integer revisionStatusId);
```

Thanks in advance!

The query creation for limiting to 1 result is defined here with FIRST & TOP included in the method name.

https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.query-methods.query-creation

Comment: not able to understand the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think "findFirst" will work when you're using an @Query, as the query will be constructed from HQL expression in the @Query rather than the fluent API passing over the method name.  Because of this, when the query returns multiple results, it will throw the exception as the Optional is told to wrap a single returned object, not a collection.  Add a LIMIT clause to the HQL query and you should be good.

Comment: I used Restrictions instead, because the method name becomes extreme long with QueryCreation from the method name. Thanks for the feedback.